# ZF2 - Is it possible in any way to add data to the Rowset after pagination?

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I have in module.php something like that

```
'OrderTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Order());
return new TableGateway('order', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
```

and in OrderTable (tablegateway):

```
$data = new Paginator(new DbTableGateway($this >tableGateway,array('customer_id'=>$customer_id)); 
$data->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
```

and now i want change $data - add something to every row? is it possible? and how?

Looking more generally - I just want to add to object Order ( new Order () ), the result of another query - in this case, the list of products.

Comment: You would use a custom Hydrator to do this for you as each row is created. Let the hydrator add the object when each row/item is created.

Comment: Thank you. Now of course it works. By the way I would like to ask if you know how such a thing is possible:

select * from album,song where album.id = song.album_id;

album.id | album.name | song.id | song.name
1 | Help | 1 | Help
1 | Help | 2 | Yesterday
2 | Revolver | 3 | Taxman
2 | Revolver | 4 | She said

and now still using tablegateway, and have oportunty to use paginator etc achieve with minimal effort Album rowset or smth similar. 2 rows with "colum" songs with list of songs.

I do not know if I made myself clear?